# FB Comments Plugin unreachable site warning

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments

I've inserted a new version of the FB social comments plugin and it shows that the URL where I posted the comments box is unreachable. I had the older version comments plugin before and it worked fine. How do I fix this? My page URL is http://www.irinadesigns.com/blog11_fun_facts.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your comments plugin's `href` is set to `http://www.irinasworld.com/blog11_fun_facts.html` which 404s. Update it to point to the correct URL.

Comment: To whomever just downvoted me: that was absolutely the root cause of th the OP's question